# How to print the name of the DLL which is unable to import?

Tags: python, visual-c++, mfc, dllimport

In my MFC application I am using the below line of code to import a python module.

```
pyImportedModuleObj = PyImport_Import(pyNameFilenameObj);
```

Even though the path is right, I am getting NULL. It is because of a python exception. I have tried to print the actual python exception.

```
    bool CheckPythonError() {
        if (PyObject *perr = PyErr_Occurred()) {
            PyObject *errobj, *errdata, *errtraceback, *pyerr, *pydata, *pytrc;

            PyErr_Fetch(&errobj, &errdata, &errtraceback);
            pyerr = NULL;
            pydata = NULL;
            CString save_error_type, save_error_data, save_traceback;
            if (errobj != NULL &&
            (pyerr = PyObject_Str(errobj)) != NULL &&     /* str(object) */
            (PyString_Check(pyerr))) {
                save_error_type = PyString_AsString(pyerr);
                pydata = PyObject_Str(errdata);
                PyString_Check(pydata);
                save_error_data = PyString_AsString(pydata);
                pytrc = PyObject_Str(errtraceback);
                if (errtraceback) {
                    save_traceback = PyString_AsString(errtraceback);
                }
                else {
                    save_traceback = "No traceback available";
                }
            }
            else {
                save_error_type = "<unknown exception type>";
            }
            Py_XDECREF(pyerr);
            Py_XDECREF(pydata);
            //WI-29387 - Replaced MessageBox with g_MsgBoxMgr.ShowMessageBox
            MessageBox(NULL, save_error_type + "\n" + save_error_data, "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
            return TRUE;
        }
        return FALSE;
    }
```

I am getting the python error as below.

[image]

I need to print the DLL name as well. Also please advice me how to solve this error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That information isn't easily available. You need to enable loader snaps to find out.

Comment: Actually my MFC application exe integrated with an install shield 2018 set up. When the exe ran alone, there are no error. But when it shows dll load error after integrating with install shield. In this case, how can I get the loader snaps? I am using Visual Studio.